# Broken coil spring

Tags: nissan, suspension

My car is a 5 1/2 years old Nissan Note with 42k miles on it. It has only driven 6000 miles since its last MOT. It is serviced every year.

I recently took my car to get 2 new tyres and asked for the tracking to be checked at same time.

The garage struggled with my tracking. They had 3 mechanics trying to sort it out so a correct reading could be taken/recorded. It took them approximately 40 minutes. The manager spoke to me advising they were having problems, but that they would sort it out.

I specifically asked the manager:

> What would cause these issues?
>
> Was there a broken part or something that needed to be repaired?

If a repair was needed, I would have left the car for the repair that day. They said that it was probably the state of our roads that had caused the problem.

---

I advised them that my MOT was due exactly a week later (being done by same garage) and I asked:

> Will my car would fail due to whatever the problem was with my tracking?

The manager said my car would ***not*** fail the MOT and that there was nothing wrong with my car.

---

***My car failed the MOT with a broken coil spring!***

I have no problem with it needing the repair as I presume this is a wear & tear issue.

***But,***

1. Should the mechanics/manager not realised that there was a problem with my car?
2. Could this have caused a lot more problems with my car if we continued to drive it?

Answer (score 4):

A spring can break at any time and it's quite a common fault.  The fact that this wasn't spotted when the workshops were unable to obtain acceptable suspension geometry settings is a cause for concern and I'd personally be thankful that it didn't cause an incident and re-evaluate my choice of workshops in future.